# Active Admin form drop down not saving selected value in database

Tags: drop-down-menu, admin

I am new to ROR and using active admin for generating a small app. I have belongs to and has many relation ships defined in the models. My app is working good for the pages where belongs to does not apply. In the page where belongs to comes into action I have drop down created by Active Admin, however when I select the values from drop down and save the form, values selected from drop down is not getting saved. below are my model controller and active admin pages codes. Please help me fix this issue.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Componentdetail do

models:

class Preference < ActiveRecord::Base

  def permitted_params
    params.permit preference: [:prefname, :prefdisplay, :helptext]
  end
  def preference_params
    params.require(:preference).permit(:prefname, :prefdisplay, :helptext)
  end
  attr_accessible :prefname, :prefdisplay, :helptext
  has_many :prefcomprelation
  #accepts_nested_attributes_for :prefcomprelation, :allow_destroy => true

 def display_name
    return self.prefname
end
def input
  self.id
end
end

class Prefcomprelation < ActiveRecord::Base

  def permitted_params
    params.permit prefcomprelation: [:comment, :preference, :componentdetail]
  end
  def prefcomprelation_params
    params.require(:prefcomprelation).permit(:comment, :preference, :componentdetail)
  end
 # def to_s
 # description
 # end
  attr_accessible :comment, :preference, :componentdetail
  #acts_as_list column: :preference, :scope => :preference
  belongs_to :preference
  #acts_as_list column: :componentdetail, :scope => :componentdetail
  belongs_to :componentdetail
  validates :comment, presence: true
  validates :preference, presence: true
  validates :componentdetail, presence: true
  #controller do
    def new
      @prefcomprelation = Prefcomprelation.new
    end
    def update
    @prefcomprelation = Prefcomprelation.new(precomprelation_params)
    @prefcomprelation.save
    end
    def create
    @prefcomprelation = Prefcomprelation.new(precomprelation_params)
    @prefcomprelation.save
    end
  #end
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  def permitted_params
    params.permit message: [:message, :componentdetail]
  end
    def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:message, :componentdetail)
  end
  attr_accessible :message, :componentdetail
  belongs_to :componentdetail
end


class Componentdetail < ActiveRecord::Base

  def permitted_params
    params.permit componentdetail: [:compname, :compdisplay, :prefcomprelation]
  end

  def componentdetail_params
    params.require(:componentdetail).permit(:compname, :compdisplay, :prefcomprelation)
  end
  attr_accessible :compname, :compdisplay, :prefcomprelation
  has_many :prefcomprelation
  #accepts_nested_attributes_for :prefcomprelation, :allow_destroy => true
  has_many :message
  #accepts_nested_attributes_for :message, :allow_destroy => true

  def name
    return self.compname
  end
end


controllers

class PreferenceController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @preference = Preference.all
  end

  def show
  end
end


class PrefcomprelationController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @prefcomprelation = Prefcomprelation.all
  end

  def create
    @prefcomprelation = Prefcomprelation.new(precomprelation_params)
    @prefcomprelation.save
  end

  def new
   @prefcomprelation = Prefcomprelation.new(precomprelation_params)
   @prefcomprelation.save
  end

  def show
  end
end


class MessageController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @message = Message.all
  end
def create
@message = Message.new(message_params)
  @message.save
end

  def show
  end
end

class ComponentdetailController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @componentdetail = Componentdetail.all
  end

  def show
  end
end


class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end

Admin Pages

ActiveAdmin.register Preference do
end

ActiveAdmin.register Prefcomprelation do


  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :comment
    column :preference

    column :created_at
    actions
  end

  filter :comment
  filter :preference
  filter :componentdetail

 form do |f|
    f.inputs "Prefcomprelation" do
      f.input :comment
      #f.inputs do
      f.input :preference

      f.input :componentdetail


      end
    f.actions
     # f.input :preference

    end

  end

ActiveAdmin.register Message do
index do
column :message
column :created_at
actions
end

form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
f.inputs 'Details' do
f.input :message
f.input :componentdetail
end
f.actions
end
end

ActiveAdmin.register Componentdetail do
end

issue comes when I try to create new Prefcomprelation and select preference and componentdetails value from the dropdown menu and try to save. 

same happens to the message page.
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    form do |f|

         f.inputs "Product Details" do

              f.input :name, :as => :select, 
                            :collection => Product.all.map{|u| ["#{u.product_name}", u.product_name]}

              f.input :description
              f.input :image
              f.input :quantity
         end
        f.actions 
    end
```

Try to add drop down like above and save select value in active admin.